# Misunderstanding the notion of occupation numbers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, notation, second-quantization, quantum-statistics

In the context of calculating the partition function of a quantum ideal gas of $N$ indistinguishable particles, we introduced the notion of ocupation numbers $n_{p,s_z}$as the number of particles in the state $|p,s_z \rangle$ where $p$ is the momentum and $s_z$ is the $z$-projection of the spin. Then we imposed that $$\sum_{p,s_z}n_{p,s_z}=N$$where $N$ is the number of particles of the gas. But I found this odd, or perhaps I'm misunderstanding something. Couldn't some particle be in the state $$|\psi \rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|p_1,1/2\rangle+|p_2,-1/2\rangle)$$ or something like that? How would this count to the occupation number $n_{p_1,1/2}$ for example?

My question is it seems that the condition is assuming that each particle is always in some common eigenstate of momentum and spin, which is surely not true, or at least, I can't see why it would be true. If the condition is not assuming that, they I am even more confused because I don't know how a superposed state between eigenstates would count to that occupation number.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, for me it is unclear what you are asking exactly. I have a feeling what you are asking about, but it is not totally clear to me. Can you give more context. To start with: Are you talking about the occupation number basis? What are the $n_p$'s? Can you give a definition? Usually, you start by a single-particle basis, e.g. $|p,\sigma\rangle$, and then construct a $N$-particle basis, which often is written as $|n_{p_1,\sigma_1},n_{p_1,\sigma_2}, n_{p_2,\sigma_1},\ldots\rangle$, and you can check the definition in any good book on many-body physics.

Comment: @TobiasFünke this is the definition I was given, and although I'm translating from portuguese, they were called occupation numbers. My professor just said $n_{p,s_z}$ is the number of particles in the gas that are in the state $|n,s_z\rangle$, that is the eigenstate of both momentum and spin associated with the eigenvalues $\vec{p}=$ and $s_z$

Comment: Ok; for me, this is by no means a mathematical suitable definition... Regarding your edit: As I said, you can build a orthonormal basis in the $N$-particle state ($N$ identical bosons or fermions. And in each of these states, there are $n_1$ particles in $p_1,\sigma_1$ etc, as the notation suggests. Since in the partition sum you are basically performing a trace, that is fine. Does that help?

Comment: @TobiasFünke he's a rather unreliable teacher, hence why I had no other choice to try to clarify what he meant here. Hopefully someone else will shed some light on this. I've looked on the recommended literature (Huang, Landau), but I didn't find anything illuminating

Comment: You are right in the sense that in a $N$-body state, of course there is no a priori reason that each particle is in a definite $p,\sigma$ state! And that is why I said the definition is kind of ambiguous. But as I tried to explain above, you can construct a (complete) ONB, where each member of this basis *is* a many-body state with $n_1$ particles in $p_1,\sigma_1$ etc. The condition $\sum n=N$ just reflects the fact that you consider $N$ (identical) bosons or fermions.

Comment: @TobiasFünke A bit, but could you substantiate why in each of those states there are $n_i$ particles in that state such that you sum them all it gives the total number of particles? I'm having a hard time figuring out why some particle can be in a superposed state like the example I gave

Comment: @TobiasFünke yes I understand as far, we're constructing the tensor product basis between eigenbasis of observables that commute right? But yeah I also find the definition ambiguous seeing as a general state in that tensor product, like you said, is not guaranteed to be any of those basis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149748/discussion-between-tobias-funke-and-lourenco-entrudo).

Comment: Apply $N$ to your state. What would you get?

Answer (score 1):

I asked my teacher again and he said this definition only applies if every particle is in some momentum and spin eigenstate. I thought a lot about this and this is the answer I came up with.

When we do statistics with a system of variable energy and number of particles we consider a set of ensembles with different energies and number of particles and we average over them, with suitable probability densities. I suppose that when treating the a quantum ideal gas of non-interacting ideal particles, to follow this approach we must consider a set of systems which are eigenstates of the total Hamiltonian; otherwise we couldn't speak of the energy of that system.

Furthermore, if the particles are non interacting, the hamiltonian is separable i.e $$H=\sum_{i=1}^NH'_i$$ This means that if the system's state is an eigenstate of the energy, it will be "akin to" a tensor product of eigenstates of the "sub" energies in the following way: let me illustrate this by restricting to the case of two particles, one with the energy eigenstates $|n_i\rangle$ and the other with eigenstates $|n_j\rangle$ (I can call them by the same letter since the particles are indistinguishable). Then if $E=E_i+E_j$, and the system's state is an eigenstate with eigenvalue $E$, $|\psi\rangle$, \begin{equation}H |\psi\rangle=H\left(\sum_{l,k} c_{lk}|n_l\rangle \otimes |n_k\rangle \right)=(E_i+E_j)\left(\sum_{l,k} c_{lk}|n_l\rangle \otimes |n_k\rangle \right)\iff \\ \sum_{l,k} c_{lk} (H'_1+H'_2)|n_l\rangle \otimes |n_k\rangle =\sum_{l,k} c_{lk}(E_i+E_j)|n_l\rangle \otimes |n_k\rangle  \iff \\ \sum_{l,k} c_{lk} (E_l+E_k)|n_l\rangle \otimes |n_k\rangle=\sum_{l,k} c_{lk}(E_i+E_j)|n_l\rangle \otimes |n_k\rangle \end{equation}
Which means $l,k$ can only take the values $i,j$. Then the general energy eigenstate will be of the form: $$|\psi \rangle=a |n_i \rangle \otimes |n_j \rangle+b |n_j \rangle \otimes |n_i \rangle$$
Since the particles are indistinguishable, $a$ is either equal to $b$ or to $-b$ (bosons or fermions). Because of that we may non-ambiguosly identify this state as being the state where one particle is in the energy level $E_i$ and the other one is in the energy level $E_j$. I believe that makes the definition of occupation numbers provided well defined and well motivated